# MVC Code First Issue getting Data from Remote SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, connection-string

My code runs without any errors but it doesn't seem to be pulling any data from my SQL Server. When debugging I get the query string below. From my understanding it should select all from the table... let me know if I'm wrong I'm new to MVC thanks for the help

[image]

**Connection String**

```
<add name="RegionalSalesManConnection" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     connectionString="Server=01DEV\SQLDEV01;Database=Caplugs_Nav_Data;Trusted_Connection=Yes" />
```

`RegionalSalesManConnection.cs`:

```
public class RegionalSalesManConnection : DbContext
{
    public RegionalSalesManConnection() : base("RegionalSalesManConnection") { }

    public DbSet<RegionalSalesManagers> RegionalManagers { get; set; }
}
```

`RegionalSalesManagers.cs`:

```
public class RegionalSalesManagers
{
    [Key]
    public string   Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`Index.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMobile.Models.RegionalSalesManagers>

<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
    @foreach(var item in Model) {
        <li>@item.Code, @item.Name</li>      
    }
</ul>
```

`HomeController.cs`:

```
private RegionalSalesManConnection db;

  public HomeController()
  {
     db = new RegionalSalesManConnection();
  }

  public ViewResult Index() {

  ViewBag.NumSessions = Sessions.All.Count;
  var model = db.RegionalManagers.ToList();

     return View(model);
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the Name field in your model consists of one single character only?

Comment: Ah I didn't notice that thank you, but still the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Code First are you dropping and recreating the database on every load? If so are you seeding any data into the table in question?

**Edit: Seeding data**

Here's an example of a Database Initializer class that will seed data:

```
public class DatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<NameOfContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(NameOfContext context)
    {
        SeedTestData(context);
        base.Seed(context);
    }

    private static void SeedTestData(NameOfContext context)
    {
        var item = new Item
        {
            Id = 1
        }
        context.DatabaseObjectBeingAddedTo.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Then in your global.asax file add the following to your Application_Start() method:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseInitializer());
```

**Second update, here is how you declare your context (linked to your database connection in your web.config via its name attribute) and the configuration for an entity (in this case RegionalSalesManager)**

**Context creation:**

```
using Data.EntityConfigurations;
using Domain.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Data.Contexts
{
    public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public ApplicationContext()
            : base("ConnectionStringName")
        { }

        public DbSet<RegionalSalesManager> RegionalSalesManagers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RegionalSalesManagerConfiguration());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

**Entity Configuration:**

```
using Domain.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

namespace Data.EntityConfigurations
{
    public class RegionalSalesManagerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<RegionalSalesManager>
    {
        public RegionalSalesManagerConfiguration()
        {
            //Table
            ToTable("RegionalSalesManagers");

            //Primary key
            HasKey(e => e.Id);

            //Properties
            Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("RegionalSalesManagerId").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So once the app is running you can use SQL Server Management Studio to view existing data in the table in question and it is present?

Comment: No it doesn't appear. I think my issue is the db isn't ever populated in the configuration file (new to ef so I just found out about this through a tutorial) I'm still trying to figure out how to populate it

Comment: I've added an example of how to seed data to my answer, let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: I'm receiving the error "There is no implicit reference conversion from '...RegionalSalesManagers' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' Also   there currently is no database (in App_Data) from what I read this should be automatically created when I run the program. Basically what I'm trying to accomplish at this point is to get my table from a remote SQL server and show it on a webpage.

Comment: I've updated my answer again to show how you create your context linked to your database connection in your web.config and then configuring entities to your database tables via a configuration file. In this case it has one column, the primary key called RegionalSalesManagerId which is mapped to the Id property of the RegionalSalesManager class.